# Is there a wall building tool in unity3d?

Tags: unity, editors, map-editor

I'm currently building a maze game in unity 3d and after building a few levels by placing and repositioning cubes by hand as walls, I think, that it would be nice if there was a tool to place walls, which are cubes with constant height and width, but have different length and rotations on the y-axis, by joints: you click to place a joint, and a wall goes in straight lines beetwen joints. So is there a tool like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pro Builder](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder) allows you to model static geometry right in the Unity editor. It's an optional package you have to install using the package manager.

But if this is going to become a larger project, then you might look into editor scripting and write your own level editor.